# How should I handle a value that is never used?

Tags: c, gcc, posix, compiler-warnings

I don't always use all return values, and sometimes I must handle return values. For instance:

```
$ make
gcc  -pedantic -std=c99 -Wall -O3 -ledit -g -DVERSION=\"v0.160425-2-gc443\"   -c -o main.o main.c
main.c: In function ‘int_handler’:
main.c:532:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     write(fileno(stdin), s, sizeof s - 1);
     ^
gcc -o shell main.o errors.c util.c pipeline.c -ledit
```

What should I do to avoid the warning? Is there a good way to "use" a variable like writing it to `/dev/null` so that the compiler won't complain? My own idea is this, which deals with the problem without ignoring the error and I can commit my code without warnings and deal with this later:

```
void int_handler(int signum) {
    if (write(fileno(stdin), s, sizeof s - 1)) {
    } else {}
}
```

Comment: Cast the unused value to `(void)` is one option.  `(void) write(...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in case of file handling functions in production-quality code, you should almost certainly handle all return values.

Otherwise, the standard way to ignore a variable or a function result, is to cast it to `(void)`.

Answer (score 3):

Typically to suppress this warning, you can do:

```
(void)write(fileno(stdin), s, sizeof s - 1);
```

But the reason for the warning is because `write()` is declared with an attribute in the header (`<unistd.h>`) which leads to the warning.

This (attribute) is not done for every function but selectively. For example, `printf()`'s return is typically ignored.
Since, you would want to check the results of IO operation, it's done for `write()`.

So, if you really want to ignore the result, you can use the `(void)func(...);` to suppress this.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to not take in account the return value of a call to `write`, as an I/O may fail it is important to take care of such an event. If you really want to remove the warning, you should explicitly ignore the return value:

```
(void)write(...);
```

Comment: It still gives me a wrning but this worked: `if (write(fileno(stdin), s, sizeof s - 1)) {
    } else {}`

Answer (score 1):

The prototype for write in the header file unistd.h has been declared as follows

```
 extern ssize_t write (int __fd, const void *__buf, size_t __n) __wur
```

and __wur has been defined as (in cdefs.h)

```
# if __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL > 0
 #  define __wur __attribute_warn_unused_result__
 # endif
 #else
 # define __attribute_warn_unused_result__ /* empty */
```

So when  you are compiling with fortify switch on,  **wur gets defined as
__attribute_warn_unused_result**.  This attribute essentially tells the compiler to throw out warning if return value of function is not used.

You can  redirect your stdout and stderr to /dev/null

```
gcc -c file.c  > /dev/null  2>&1
```

and get rid of the warning (though even error is redirected to null) or you can redirect to file as

```
gcc -c warn.c  > xx 2>&1
```

Hope this helps . And like said above,  always check the value of "write", the error will automatically vanish
:)